# How to escape double quotes and exclamation mark in password?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-scripting, sh

I have the following code:

```
curl -s --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"$1\",\"password\":\"$2\"}" http://apiurl
```

In the above `curl` command I want to escape the `"` and `!` in the password.

I have modified the curl command as below but it doesn't seem to work

```
curl -s --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"$1\",\"password\":\"$2\"}" http://apiurl
```

Answer (score 0):

${password//!/\!} will substitute every ! in the password with ! The extra \ signifies that we are looking to replace every ! and not just the first one.

The same logic can be used for " Alternatively, you may be able to enclose the complete -d variable in single quotes instead of double quotes and this may negate the need for escaping the double quotes.